# I use flowable. How can I get access to activiti:expression in java code for using spring beans or something else

Tags: java, spring, repository, activiti, flowable

Here my bpmn file:

```xml
 <process id="weather-forecast-flow" name="weather-forecast-flow" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="sid-2972fcc9-6bb9-41ce-a716-77550fc8ac6a"/>
    <userTask id="userRequest" name="userRequest"/>
    <serviceTask id="requestToWeatherApi" activiti:exclusive="true" name="requestToWeatherApi" activiti:class="by.singularity.weatherforecast.service.MakeRequestHandler"/>
    <serviceTask id="saveToDb" activiti:exclusive="true" name="saveToDb" activiti:class="by.singularity.weatherforecast.service.SaveToDbHandler" activiti:expression="${**weatherInfoRepository**}"/>
    <endEvent id="sid-b8787eb3-a925-485c-90bd-a3b44ad94a0d"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-5112b088-2527-4a5f-8ce0-7d1c56e4dbea" sourceRef="sid-2972fcc9-6bb9-41ce-a716-77550fc8ac6a" targetRef="userRequest"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-61b1b15e-6611-483b-90be-723d6751fc0b" sourceRef="userRequest" targetRef="requestToWeatherApi"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-4a5919ec-70d3-4eea-8233-03d6ce62341d" sourceRef="requestToWeatherApi" targetRef="saveToDb"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-45d2b862-994f-4cdc-8298-b0e27e3a8584" sourceRef="saveToDb" targetRef="sid-b8787eb3-a925-485c-90bd-a3b44ad94a0d"/>
  </process>
```

And class, in which I want to use weatherInfoRepository (it's bold on schema):

```java
public class SaveToDbHandler implements JavaDelegate {

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) {
        Map<?,?> weatherInfoOpt = (Map<?, ?>) delegateExecution.getVariable("weatherInfoMap");
        AtomicReference<WeatherInfo> weatherInfo = new AtomicReference<>();

        String name = (String) (weatherInfoOpt).get("name");
        Double temperature =(Double) ((Map<?,?>)(weatherInfoOpt).get("main")).get("temp");
        weatherInfo.set(new WeatherInfo(name, temperature, new Date()));
        delegateExecution.setVariable("weatherInfo",weatherInfo.get());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Flowable for a service task you have 3 options:

- `class` - a fully qualified name of an implementation of `JavaDelegate`
- `expression` - an expression that will be executed e.g. `${10 + x}`
- `delegateExpression` - an expression that resolves to an instance of `JavaDelegate`. e.g. a Spring Bean

You can read more about this in https://www.flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch07b-BPMN-Constructs#java-service-task

You cannot combine those 3, you can only use one of them.